How does Reddit display 'x people here' on a certain post?
This is what I mean. I am interested in how do they display this, and does this mean on desktop only or does it count mobile users as well. Interested to know.
I haven't tried anything yet. I'm just interested in this specific thing. Maybe some design people already know this, I suspect it has to do something with desktop users only. But I am quite clueless about this.
